# React app exiting in docker container with exit code 0

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to create a docker-compose setup with nginzx, flask, and react. I started my react app with react-create-app (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) and haven't changed anything from it yet.

My Dockerfile for the react app is:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --verbose

# Bundle app source
COPY . .


EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The compose script is:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.15
        container_name: nginx
        volumes:
            - ../:/var/www
            - ./nginx-dev.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        ports:
            - 80:80
        networks:
            - my-network
        depends_on:
            - flask
            - react
    react:
        build:
            context: ../react-app/
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        container_name: react
        volumes:
            - ../react-app:/usr/src/app
        networks:
            my-network:
                aliases:
                    - react-app
        expose:
            - 3000
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
    flask:
        ...
networks:
    my-network:
```

The flask and nginx containers start fine, the output for react is:

```
react    | 
react    | > react-app@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app
react    | > react-scripts start
react    | 
react    | ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://my-ip-address/
react    | ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
react    | ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /usr/src/app/public
react    | ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
react    | Starting the development server...
react    | 
react    | 
react    | npm verb lifecycle react-app@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
react    | npm verb lifecycle react-app@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
react    | npm verb lifecycle react-app@0.1.0~start: CWD: /usr/src/app
react    | npm info lifecycle react-app@0.1.0~poststart: react-app@0.1.0
react    | npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
react    | npm timing npm Completed in 1727ms
react    | npm info ok 
react exited with code 0
```

Comment: note that if I cd into react-app and run `npm start`, everything works as expected.

Comment: Try setting tty true as well.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Adding: `stdin_open: true` to the React component of my docker-compose file fixed my issue.

**Example:**

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    react:
        build:
            context: ../react-app/
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        container_name: react
        volumes:
            - ../react-app:/usr/src/app
        networks:
            my-network:
                aliases:
                    - react-app
        expose:
            - 3000
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        stdin_open: true
```

Comment: worked! https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688

Answer (score 14):

It looks like an issue with [React-Scripts] v3.4.1. Please look into this [link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688)

Comment: yes, this is very relevant. Thank you very much. I will post the snippet that fixed my setup.

Answer (score 5):

Ran into same issue. Below mentioned steps resolved my problem:
1. add **stdin_open: true**

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  nginx:
    .
    .
  react:
    stdin_open: true
    .
    .
```

2. Do not forget to build the container again after the above mentioned change is made.

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up --build
```

Answer (score 0):

As the issue is with react-scripts version > 3.4.0 as with the posted link from sandeep-reddy, you could pin the version that is installed by using these lines in the Dockerfile (credit Michael Herman).

Edit: Looks like you still need the line `stdin_open:true` in docker-compose.yml file for it to work.

```
RUN npm ci
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.0 -g --silent
```

Comment: why did you post this as a new answer if you still need `stdin_open: true`?

Comment: I thought initially solution would work as I saw it being used somewhere else admittedly without testing it properly. That's why I made the correction afterwards. I can delete my answer if that's better

Comment: nah bro keep the answer