# I am getting error when I try to dockerize my MERN application

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here is my Dockerfile for React.js with the error I got in terminal:

```
FROM node:8
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install

RUN npm build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Error:-

```
react_1     | 
react_1     | > ecom-panther@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app
react_1     | > react-scripts start
react_1     | 
react_1     | ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.18.0.2/
react_1     | ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
react_1     | ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /usr/src/app/public
react_1     | ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
react_1     | Starting the development server...
react_1     | 
ecom-panther_react_1 exited with code 0
```

For Node and Express, I got this:

```
express_1   | (node:30) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
express_1   | server is running on port: 5000
express_1   | (node:30) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
express_1   |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
express_1   |     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
express_1   |     at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
express_1   |     at createConnection (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:561:14)
express_1   |     at connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:994:11)
express_1   |     at makeConnection (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:31:7)
express_1   |     at callback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:264:5)
express_1   |     at Socket.err (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:294:7)
express_1   |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
express_1   |     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
express_1   |     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
express_1   |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:73:8)
express_1   |     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
express_1   |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
express_1   | (node:30) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
express_1   | (node:30) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Docker file for backend:-

```
FROM node:8
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version:  '3' # specify docker-compose version

# Define the service/container to be run
services:
  react: #name of first service
    build: client #specify the directory of docker file
    ports:
    - "3000:3000" #specify port mapping

  express: #name of second service
    build: server #specify the directory of docker file
    ports:
    - "5000:5000" #specify port mapping
    links:
    - database #link this service to the database service

  database: #name of third service
    image: mongo #specify image to build contasiner flow 
    ports:
    - "27017:27017" #specify port mapping
```

How I can run frontend at browser and is there any easy approach to do this in a better way ?

Comment: It's done now..maybe now it is more helpful to you to understand

Comment: It's better, but now the errors/logs are removed. Please copy the errors from your IDE, in text format, to the question. They also should not be presented as images.

Comment: The logs in the first image are the most important - they contain the answer. Please ping me at `@halfer` once you have edited again and I will supply an answer.

Comment: @halfer please check now

Comment: Better, but please also add your `express 1` logs. You've added your `react 1` logs only.

Comment: Hey @halfer thanks but it works fine by this ref.https://stackoverflow.com/a/60902143/5699811

Comment: Aha, there are two problems then. I am looking at another one (a database connection failure).

Comment: yes please suggest me for that

Comment: It looks like you are connecting in your `express` service to a database at `localhost:27017`. This would have worked in a non-Docker arrangement where you have a database on the same server. Since you have containerised your database separately, you should think of your database as being on a different server (even if the db container happens to run on the same Docker host). Try connecting to `database:27017` in your code - the DNS name `database` should give you an IP that points to the MongoDB instance.

Answer (score 2):

Error 1:

Add `stdin_open: true` to your `react` service, like:

```
...
services:
  react: #name of first service
    build: client #specify the directory of docker file
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
    - "3000:3000" #specify port mapping
...
```

You might need to rebuild or clean cached so "**docker-compose up --build**" or "**docker-compose build --no-cache**" then "**docker-compose up**"

Error 2:

In your database connections line in your index.js file or whatever you named should have :

```
mongodb://database:27017/
```

where "database" is your named MongoDB service. You can use your container IP address too with `docker inspect <container>` and use the IP the see there too. Ideally you want to have a ENV in your Dockerfile or `docker-compose.yml`:

```
ENV MONGO_URL mongodb://database:27017/
```

Comment: I haven't see you have two problems, now you have my two solutions, Please remember you have two related question to your problems and a lot of people is trying to help you.

Comment: Hey @halfer

When i try to dockerize only my react app then it gives error.
Command :- sudo docker run -p 3000:3000 react:app
Error:- 
> my-app@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app
> react-scripts start

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.2/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /usr/src/app/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

Comment: @Deepikavijay: that sounds like the problem that MikZuit is trying to help you solve ("Error 1"). Did you try the suggestion here?

Comment: but he told me to do this docker-compose yml file but i just create a seperate docker file and create image and then run same image.

This is my dockerfile:-
FROM node:10
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

# RUN npm install --silent
# Copy app source code
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]

i need to add here "stdin_open: true"

Comment: @Deepikavijay the problem you're facing is a common issue with react-script https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688 . I suggest you to have your files at the point WHEN YOU ASK this question, and just do the changes I suggested, just one line in your docker-compose.yml . I then run with "docker-compose up --build" or the other command I updated in my answer..