# My react docker webpage does not bind to the host

Tags: docker, react-scripts

I have a react app whihc I can perfectly run it without doccker on the VM by running "npm run start"..However, when I make within docker images and run the docker it doesn't come up..my dockerfile is as follow:

```
FROM node:12
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /var/tmp/thermo && chown -R root:root /var/tmp/thermo
WORKDIR /var/tmp/thermo
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "run","start"]
```

I can succesffult create the docker image and then run it,

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name thermo-*** thermo-***
```

however the container always exits, the container logs is as follow:

```
[root@*****]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
03701ed96bca        thermo-api          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   17 minutes ago      Exited (0) 17 minutes ago                       thermo-api-app
[root@t****]#
[root@****]# docker logs 03701ed96bca

> material-kit-pro-react@1.9.0 start /var/tmp/thermo
> export PORT=3000 && react-scripts start

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.2/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /var/tmp/thermo/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server..
```

then when I curl to my website ("curl localhost:3000") nothing pops up,
I am not sure where I am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [Container networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/). You did not publish port for container. add `-p 3000:3000` into [Docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) command

Comment: yes, I did, I editted my question..

Comment: so I think your `docker ps -a` should show the port. [same issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29750). are your sure your service is start successfully?

Comment: From the log it seems bind with `172.17.0.2`, change script section in npm to `HOST=0.0.0.0 react-scripts start`

Comment: even though, I used HOST=0.0.0.0 react-scripts start, it binds to 172.17.0.2

Comment: Does it help to add a `docker run -i` option?  This addresses a bug in react-scripts; see [React app exiting in docker container with exit code 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60895246/react-app-exiting-in-docker-container-with-exit-code-0/60902143#60902143).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try take another look at your code, the container is exit immediately after you started the container.
By the way, the `npm run start` is just for development environment, why don't you build the code and serve it by Nginx

My opinion is you should build your code then use Dockerfile example in your way, the Nginx will serve your app

Dockerfile

```
# build environment
FROM node:lts-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build
RUN react-scripts build

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

You can use this nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    location /web {
            alias   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnaks for your answer it solve my problem. Can you explain why we need two production and build environments?

Comment: @Mehdi Those "#"  is just a comment. In this case, if you want to serve your website, you'll need a web server to do that, we use Nginx in this case, npm is a package manager, not a web server