# npm update check failed for Docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a React app running in a docker container with a following .Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY /mvp-client-app ./
RUN npm install --silent

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

When I start the container I see the following error message

```
> mvp-client-app@0.1.0 start /app
> react-scripts start

Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable: 0.0.0.0
If this was unintentional, check that you haven't mistakenly set it in your shell.
Learn more here: 

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.18.0.4/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...


┌──────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│           npm update check failed            │
│     Try running with sudo or get access      │
│     to the local update config store via     │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /.config │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I was not able to add to the proposed command to the Dockerfile. How can I get rid of the message and start the container?

We are using docker-compose

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  mvp-client:
    container_name: mvp-client
    build:
      context: ./MVP
      dockerfile: mvp-client-app/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_ENV=development
      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
      - HOST=0.0.0.0
      - PORT=3001
    user:
      999:999
```

I try to run the container by `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build mvp-client` and `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up mvp-client` (intentionally running only the one container as others work fine). I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Gitlab CI/CD pipeline.

Here is the `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "mvp-client-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@blueprintjs/core": "^3.31.0",
    "@blueprintjs/icons": "^3.20.1",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.0.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.4.8",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "debug": "^4.1.1",
    "echarts": "^4.7.0",
    "echarts-for-react": "^2.0.15-beta.1",
    "immer": "^7.0.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "node-gyp": "^7.1.0",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-ga": "^3.1.2",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0",
    "react-lines-ellipsis": "^0.14.1",
    "react-mosaic-component": "^4.1.1",
    "react-notifications": "^1.6.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.2",
    "react-spinners": "^0.9.0",
    "rebuild": "^0.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9009 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.0.3",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.0.3",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.0.3",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.0.3",
    "@storybook/addon-storysource": "^6.0.3",
    "@storybook/addons": "^6.0.3",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.1.4",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you starting the container?  (Are you using volumes to mount an old version of your `node_modules` directory over what the image builds?)

Comment: I tried to reproduce, but everything is working on my end. Can you share the package.json and a minimal app.js that can help us reproduce the error? Also the `docker run` or the `docker-compose` you're using to bring up the containers could give us more clues.

Comment: How do you run the container ?

Comment: I have updated the question with further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was solved by adding `stdin_open: true` to `docker-compose.yml` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60895246/react-app-exiting-in-docker-container-with-exit-code-0) for further details).

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  mvp-client:
    container_name: mvp-client
    build:
      context: ./MVP
      dockerfile: mvp-client-app/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_ENV=development
      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
      - HOST=0.0.0.0
      - PORT=3001
    user:
      999:999
    stdin_open: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't using using `docker-compose`, so this solution did not work for me.
However, I got to the root cause, and this might help someone.
`npm` is looking for config in user's home, and with Docker scenario, there sometimes is no user and hence no home directory. Assigning

`env HOME [same as WORKDIR]`

in `Dockerfile` helped a lot.