# Docker: React container fails build

Tags: reactjs, docker

I was using a mac laptop to run my project and it worked but I started using a new one and now my project doesn't compile.
I'm currently using Docker Desktop v3.0.4 on macOS Big Sur v11.1
If I run my react project without Docker it compiles and runs. So i'm assuming its a docker issue but can't figure out what it is. Maybe a version issue.

docker-compose.yml:

```
 version: "3.2"
 services:
   frontend:
     build: ./frontend
     volumes:
       - ./frontend:/app
        #One-way volume to use node_modules from inside image
       - /app/node_modules
     ports:
       - "3000:3000"
     #tty: true
     command: npm start
```

Dockerfile:

```
 # Use an official node runtime as a parent image
 FROM node:8
 
 ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn
 #allows app_env to be set during build (defaults to empty string)
 ARG app_env 
 #sets an environment variable to app_env argument, this way the variable will persist in the container for use in code
 ENV APP_ENV $app_env
 
 #all subsequent commands will now be run from inside this folder
 WORKDIR /app/
 
 #copy dependencies file
 COPY package.json /app/
 # Install dependencies
 RUN npm install
 
 
 # Add rest of the client code
 COPY . /app/
 
 EXPOSE 3000
 
 CMD npm start
```

When I run `docker-compose --verbose up  --build` the output is

```
 urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.41/containers/35ad92f5ac5ac433cedc991461be3b2d58dec97176db32e656010a4529f1eb49/start HTTP/1.1" 204 0
 compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker start -> None
 Creating websites_frontend_1 ... done
 compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
 compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Finished processing: <Service: frontend>
 compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
 Attaching to websites_frontend_1
 compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events <- (filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=websites', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']}, decode=True)
 urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.41/events?filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dwebsites%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 None
 compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events -> <docker.types.daemon.CancellableStream object at 0x10a619f90>
 frontend_1  |
 frontend_1  | > internal-beta-frontend@0.1.0 start /app
 frontend_1  | > react-scripts start
 frontend_1  |
 frontend_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.18.0.2/
 frontend_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
 frontend_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
 frontend_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
 frontend_1  | Starting the development server...
 frontend_1  |
 compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait <- ('35ad92f5ac5ac433cedc991461be3b2d58dec97176db32e656010a4529f1eb49')
 compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('35ad92f5ac5ac433cedc991461be3b2d58dec97176db32e656010a4529f1eb49')
 urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.41/containers/35ad92f5ac5ac433cedc991461be3b2d58dec97176db32e656010a4529f1eb49/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
 urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.41/containers/35ad92f5ac5ac433cedc991461be3b2d58dec97176db32e656010a4529f1eb49/wait HTTP/1.1" 200 None
 compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait -> {'Error': None, 'StatusCode': 0}
 websites_frontend_1 exited with code 0
 compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': '',
  'Args': ['npm', 'start'],
  'Config': {'AttachStderr': False,
             'AttachStdin': False,
             'AttachStdout': False,
             'Cmd': ['npm', 'start'],
             'Domainname': '',
             'Entrypoint': ['docker-entrypoint.sh'],
             'Env': ['PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
                     'NODE_VERSION=8.17.0',
 ...
```

Why isn't my project building? What do I have to do to get it running?

Comment: It seems like it is running. Have you verified if the container is actually running with `docker ps`?

Comment: @vpalmerini nothing shows up when i do `docker ps`. The log shows `websites_frontend_1 exited with code 0`

Comment: Does setting `stdin_open: true` in the Compose settings help?  (See: [React app exiting in docker container with exit code 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60895246/react-app-exiting-in-docker-container-with-exit-code-0))

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and what solved it was to exclude the project from `Spotlight` indexing tool. It seems that this one uses a lot of resources and that made the build fail. Go to `System preferences` and then search for `Spotlight`. Then go to `Privacy` tab and add the directories that have your projects. That might help.