# React server does not start in docker and exits after message Starting development server

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile

I have this issue where my react app won’t start in docker. It reads “starting the development server” but it does nothing after that. Any ideas on what I might be missing please?

[image]

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
USER root
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl gnupg
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "start"]
EXPOSE 8082
# docker build -t gatling_tool .
# docker run -p 8082:3000 gatling_tool
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: This sounds like [React app exiting in docker container with exit code 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60895246/react-app-exiting-in-docker-container-with-exit-code-0); is it the same symptom and do the solutions there help?  How are you starting the container and what _text_ output does it produce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
USER root
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl gnupg
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "start"]
EXPOSE 8082
# docker build -t gatling_tool .
# docker run -it -p 8082:3000 gatling_tool
```

Try running the above code with -it flag which I added
for more info check - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#assign-name-and-allocate-pseudo-tty---name--it

Comment: Great, thanks very much. So I added the -it flag to the run command and it worked.  Not sure I understand it why though if you wouldn't mind elaborating on it a bit more please?

Comment: So basically reactjs dev mode is not supported by docker if interactive shell is not running so I flag is for interactive shell and t flag makes a pseudo terminal, Better explanation of pseudo terminal can be found here -https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21147/what-are-pseudo-terminals-pty-tty

Comment: Ah cool, thank you for explaining that. I'll read it through.